# Is a company order to switch to a certain IDE a red flag?

Tags: management, tools, ide, startup, eclipse

I recently joined a rapidly growing startup. In the past 3 months the development team has grown from 4 to 12.  Until now they were very [laissez-faire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laissez-faire) about what developers used to do their work. In fact one of the things I initially found attractive about the company is that most programmers used Linux, or whatever OS they felt best suited their efforts.

Now orders, without discussion, have come down that everyone is to switch to Eclipse. A fine editor. I prefer SublimeText2, but it's just my personal taste.

Just to be clear: we are a JS team using Backbone and Eclipse just isn't good at understanding Backbone code.  This means that those on the team who use a /good/ IDE (PHP Storm), have to go back to doing a lot of search-find-oh-wait-where-was-I-three-steps-ago kind of things instead of just ctrl+clicking and using back/ forward - probably diminishing productivity by say 15% and enjoyment by 50%...

Is this a red flag? It seems capricious and unreasonably controlling to tell developers (non-MS) what IDE or tool-sets to use if they are already settled in and productive.

Comment: What is your build process?  What needs to be in place for the characters you type to become binary code to go to customers.

Comment: When you say "without discussion", do you mean with you or anyone else on the team? Perhaps a vocal minority on the team asked for it?

Comment: This is a start-up. If management unilaterally makes a decision like affecting development, without discussion, it could be a major red flag regardless of what it's about.

Comment: No - there are a myriad of reasons for going to a single IDE: licensing, process, continuity, consistency...

Comment: Calling Eclipse an "editor" is like calling a shopping mall a grocery store. When it comes to editing text-files, there are other tools which do that much better, but when it comes to developing Java code there are few tools which come close.

Comment: So it's a red flag, and *then what*?   Since you've been at this job for less than 3 months, [you might have to stick there anyway](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/job-hopping-is-it-a-problem).

Comment: Have you questioned the decider about the reason and the unilateralism?

Comment: This is such a classic Java religious war -- I love how IDE choice isn't really an issue in .Net shops...

Comment: A growing company trying to establish a standard early on is a smart one in my book (no matter what it is)! Put everybody on the same page and build up expertise with a common IDE. Then the team becomes more efficient because everyone can help each other, and can share code more easily without having to worry about tab space width, encoding and things like that.

Comment: Eclipse is a whole environment, not just an editor.  Maybe IT found that dealing with every special snowflake at a growing company was becoming a huge and onerous task and wanted to standardize.  Maybe there's a tool in the Eclipse ecosystem management want to use soon.  Maybe 12 different auto-formatting editors was pissing off your repository and causing extra builds.  Possibly unlicensed tools "from home" worry management who don't want to get sued.  Maybe you're the new guy, do you really expect to be consulted on broad IT and development decisions?  Could be a million reasons, all sane.

Comment: No decision like this ever happens "without discussion." Perhaps what you meant to say is that you weren't part of the discussion, and no one asked for your input.

Comment: Depends on what "without discussion" means.  If the head boss just decided all devs must use eclipse, no exceptions for no reason and the devs are upset, that seems like a red flag.  If a policy was set for standardization (saying we won't pay for VisualStudio, etc) don't want to maintain instructions for how to set up build environments for other IDEs, or it resolves other issues (have eclipse in multiple VMs for testing), that's great.  I wouldn't start applying elsewhere over this trivial issue -- but if the 4-12 devs are upset at arbitrary orders coming from above, talk to your boss.

Comment: Is your job developing Eclipse plugins or something? Is this just a case of dog-fooding?

Comment: Do you consider the management to be qualified for that kind of decision? Were you presented with the reasons for making this decision, and how they reached it?

Comment: You should consider the original laissez-faire attitude to the red flag. For the company to fail to see the value of a consistent development process is asking for trouble later. You run the same risk the builders of the tower of Babylon ran, where at some point the ability to communicate between team members will be hobbled by the lack of a consistent work-flow. That said, they should have given this proper consideration and discussion when the start-up was young. One would have expected that to be a time when knowledgeable developers were in place who could make such a rational decision.

Comment: @Pavel Shved:  Red flag does not mean I'm jumping ship, or even thinking about it.

Comment: @rnicholson "Without discussion" means without consulting anyone beneath senior management.. not team leaders, not senior architects not anyone but the CTO.

Comment: It looks like the boss has just seen the bill for 5, or so, IDE's + other tools that they wern't expecting and nipped it in the bud.

Comment: Acknowledging the answer-example of multiple version control software, I'd hope that tool standards would be more of the black list (what's not allowed) kind. I've seen web pages being developed using microsoft word; I swear it's true.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

"Now orders, **without discussion**, have come down that everyone is to switch to Eclipse."

I think that *this* is the real red flag. Your team is the expert on software development and the one to be affected by the decision, and yet you did not get to say a word in the discussion that resulted in this order?

It sounds like over-managing by pointy-haired bosses. Does the decision making person/team have relevant insight for that decision?

---

Given that the decision makers are qualified enough for such a decision, not asking for the dev team's opinion has at least two shortcomings:

- The team does not feel involved. Involving the team should be a priority for management. I would not like to work as a dev somewhere where my opinion about such central issues as IDE is not valued enough to even be asked for. Granted that asking for someone's opinion and then deciding against it may be worse, but in that case I'd expect a solid rationale for that decision.
- The management, however experienced, does not work 100% with development of this specific code. Assuming that the people who do don't have interesting insight at all would be naïve. Of course it may be so that the managers had thought of everything the devs come up with, but the only way to know is to ask.

Comment: Nonsense.  Just because the team wasn't consulted doesn't mean the higher ups are clueless.  Its interesting as a non-Java developer, I know Eclipse is the IDE to use pretty much, but never heard of the OPs favorite until he posted it.  It would be a mistake to allow the team to standardize on an IDE that's uncommon, creating problems with recruiting other new developers.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the management is clueless, but they seem to think that the development team is since they didn't even ask for their opinion. That's a problem.

Comment: Have you considered that the "upper management" may be senior developers?  Some organizations have many layers?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: my reference to pointy hairdos might have been a bit exaggerated. I completed my answer to state that even with experienced managers, asking the devs themselves is a good idea.

Comment: You're reading way too much into this.  Management may have other concerns, like support options, and it may have come down to something that was fairly popular with a reasonable support cost (I'm talking about paid support incidents).  If that's the case, there may have been no other choice, so what would be the sense in asking the developers?  Also, have you tried to get even a small number (10-15) of developers to agree on something?  There's a reason they say getting developers to agree is like hoarding cats.

Comment: @Andy: The answer to that is "Eclipse is the only supported environment."

Comment: @Joshua Yes, and making Eclipse the only environment to use ensures a dev doesn't get stuck on an issue without support on what would have been his IDE of choice.

Comment: @Andy Hoarding cats is easy (speak to any spinster), hearding them is another matter entirely. ;o)

Comment: @JW01 Ahh, I got the wrong word.  But wouldn't it be herding? :-)

Comment: @Any: Couldn't agree more with "have you tried to get even a small number (10-15) of developers to agree on something?", might as well try to get a group of 3 year-olds to agree on something . . . and I say this as a developer.

Comment: @Andy. Yes. Ha ha. Hoisted by my own petard.

Answer (score 63):

It is reasonable that when you working together on a common project, that on every workstation you have all the tools available to edit/build/debug your software, and that the core tools for doing about 90% of the development are known to everyone in the team. That goal is harder to achieve if your team is growing and everyone uses his personal favorite toolset - the more people, the more opinions. And the administrative work gets easier, too, if you don't let the number of tools grow more than necessary.

Of course, if one developer insists to use his personal favorite editor, that may be ok as long as he can make sure the source does not look or behave differently in the main editor of the team (in your case Eclipse), so if dev B has to to edit the source of dev A, dev B should not be forced to learn the personal favorite editor of A to be able to change the source effectively. But beware, if the two have to work together from time to time in front of the same display (or do some pair programming), things are often easier if the choosen editor is well-known by both.

Comment: First of all, it's rare that a developer has to make changes on someone else's machine.  I agree with "the more people, the more opinions", but that's not a problem unless people try to impose opinions on others. Re the source, all projects should have an automatic one-command build process. As long as that works, and the code follows conventions, it doesn't matter which IDE people are using. Most IDEs are intuitive for simple things (they each have their own benefits for more complex tasks), so pair programming isn't a problem. If there are questions, the developer using the IDE can answer.

Comment: If you both know the language, looking at a different editor really isn't a problem.  Some syntax is highlighted differently and the filename may be in a different place, but there's no problem unless you're actually _using_ another developer's setup.

Comment: I work at google and in my particular team one person uses Eclipse on person uses intellij I use Emacs with evil mode to emulate Vim and one person uses Vim itself. We work fine with each other and the tool differences are no problem.  It does help that we all use the same build system and have a set style guide for reading code but that has little to do with the editor choice for each individual.

Comment: @JeremyWall: as I said, it may be ok, if your source code is displayed equally in all editors you are using and you don't do much pair programming.

Comment: @JeremyWall : Just because your team of developers can work like that, does not mean that all teams can work that way, and in fact, I'd consider a team of Google developers to be outside the norm.

Comment: @JamesP.Wright Hand-holding developers into an IDE choice is extremely limiting. I will concede that there are projects where this is exactly the right thing to do (using a custom in-house DSL maybe); however, I disagree that JeremyWall's situation is different just because he works for google. I've been a part of may teams where exactly the scenario he mentions has worked flawlessly. BTW, a single-command build process, unit tests, coding standards, and unit tests are all going to help here. If you aren't doing that, then by all means, I agree, everything is going to be hard.

Comment: @wilmoore : My point was, JeremyWall's situation is different...as all situations are different...therefore saying "it works for my team so your bosses are doing it wrong." isn't a good answer.

Comment: @JamesP.Wright fair enough :)

Comment: I used to work in a company called Zedge once, among with ex-Google/Fast/Yahoo  people, and we all used different IDEs and platforms. We used Windows, Mac, Linux, Eclipse, Vim, Emacs, intelliJ, etc etc... We still managed to make great software. (e.g for me: the Zedge Android app). I would probably have been provoked/annoyed if my IDE was dictated by someone else.

Answer (score 25):

For pair programming sake, it's nice if both parties infront of the screen has the same skills when using the keyboard. It's also nice to know that, if your project has special configuration needs in the IDE, then It's configured the same way for everybody. Getting a new developer started is easier when the tools are the same for everyone.

But if you compare that to just trying to be most effective, then it's not really worth it

Comment: +1 for noting benefit of similar development environments when pair programming

Comment: +1. I couldn't agree more. Working with multiple developers each having their own preferred tools and ways of coding can be hell! For example, you may want to enforce space over tabs, a specific indent size, and UTF-8 encoding for all your sources. I had to go through this in my team before and we had to have everyone use the same IDE in the end exactly for the reasons mentioned above. Any serious developer wouldn't have to spend long to adapt to a new IDE anyway, so I don't see the harm in it. It also makes it way easier for new members to get up to speed if everyone uses the same tool.

Comment: @Yanick: Space over tabs, indent size, encoding... All these kind of parameters must live in the coding standard, which all developers must comply with. It does not matter how they want to comply with them, does it? Formatting requirements should focus on the result being correct, not on how to get there. If the devs need to switch IDE to get the correct formatting, then I wouldn't call them "serious developers", sorry for being bold.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it's a bit of a red flag that management considers itself a better judge of which tools you would be more efficient with than you are.

Comment: Strongly depends on the reasons WHY the IDE should be the same.

Comment: We are not sure from the question who made the decision or why. The term "without discussion" could mean that they didn't include the new guy.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I hope that's the case. If they don't even let the developers decide the IDE/Editor, it's hardly a startup environment. Maybe they will start working on Android related products and chose Eclipse for that. But making it sound like an Order is kinda rude.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: can you see any good reason why the management would know better than the OP?

Comment: @Gauthier One reason might be that they want to use the Eclipse `.project` and `.classpath` files with ant4eclipse to allow Ant to build the Eclipse projects.  If not everyone use Eclipse this might break.  It is then a political management decision that everyone should use Eclipse.  Satisfied? (And we still do not know why it was enforced)

Comment: I don't have the rep to downvote, but I disagree this perspective. Even if the tool decreed by management were *in fact* not the best, it would be better than having no standardisation. Clearly the devs aren't capable of taking the decision about which is "best", since left to their own devices they've all chosen **different** tools. It's fatuous to claim different tools work better in different contexts, since most of those devs won't actually become fluent in very many anyway.

Comment: "Clearly the devs aren't capable of taking the decision about which is "best", since left to their own devices they've all chosen different tools"  They're choosing the best (most productive) tool for *themselves*.  Everyone has different experience and work patterns.  They can all be right.

Comment: Rather its smart to standarize, and pick a popular IDE ensuring that incoming devs are likely already familar with it.  If you can't figure out how to be productive in any IDE, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Andy Thats' not actually true, as the disagreements of Vim vs Emacs show.  And those are primarily text editors, not full IDEs.  It can take _years_ to get up to speed in a new environment.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I failed to get my point across. What I question is not whether to standardize on a given IDE is good or not, but whether management is more qualified than the development team for making this kind of decision, and that to such a degree that they don't even need to consult them.

Comment: @Gauthier I just mentioned one reason. You should ask the original poster that, to get the actual reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I disagree strongly. It's possible that each developer is the most efficient individually using different tools than each of the other team members. As long as there are no conflicts, then this could lead to a higher level of overall efficiency than if they all used the same editor.

Comment: @matt b: We can only agree to differ. I think in a professional environment, standardisation is sufficiently important to outweigh all but the most extreme errors in identifying the "best choice of standard". Would you have each soldier in your nation's army free to choose his own brand and model of rifle from a global catalogue?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: asked. And for the record, I am with you for the build environment requirements example. But it should not matter in which program the source files are edited (original poster seems to imply that they are not allowed to edit in anything else than Eclipse). I have actually been editing files in my personal editor and alt+tabbing to an IDE for building. It sounds cumbersome and it is, but I found it better than writing code in the joke of an editor that was included in the IDE.

Comment: @Gauthier there are lot of things that "should not matter", but prove to do so anyway.  I would expect that there is a horror story behind this question.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen or they can be stubborn.  I once knew a person who copied all files from the Unix server down to his pc for editing in his favorite program before uploading them again.  Manually.  Better?  More efficient?  Good question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's not a valid comparison.  The reason for that is that the government provides expensive rifle-specific services. 1. Training. A rifle is a deadly piece of machinery, so thorough standardized training is essential. Further, many new soldiers do not have prior experience with another combat rifle. 2. Purchase. Due to cost, the government *has* to buy in bulk. 3. Maintenance/Replacement. In contrast, typically, no IDE training is given. At best, there's a walk-through. And IDEs are cheap, so developers can buy their own, or the company can (it doesn't *have* to buy in bulk).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, in such cases you can usually find an more efficient way to use the editor they're good at.  For example, many programs have a SFTP or FTP access mode.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen not back then, no.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, fair enough.

Answer (score 14):

It's not a red flag in itself.

Sometimes **management need to take decisions**. Any issues that require standardisation on something tend to fall into that category. I once worked at a client who had allowed standards to drift for a few years and they had 20+ different SCM tools. What started as independent choice by different development teams turned into a logistical nightmare that severely hampered sharing of skills and collaboration on code across the organisation. Integrated build were..... er..... not very integrated.....

Furthermore, it's **not practical or necessary to consult everyone for every decision**. The extent to which this needs to be done depends on the culture of the organisation and the importance / complexity of the decision. Typically you'd take one of these less consultation-heavy options:

1. Make the decision yourself, if you have sufficient knowledge of the pros/cons and it's not an important enough decision to require wide consultation.
2. Consult with a few key individuals (who would probably be the senior developers most qualified to take the decision).
3. Raise the fact that you are making a decision to everyone who might be affected (email, town hall meeting, team meetings). Say what you think the right decision is but that you're willing to change this if new evidence emerges to the contrary. Invite people to come forward individually if they have some important views
4. Invite people to form a sub-team to review options and recommend a decision. Good option if it is genuinely a close call, you don't know the answer and you want those involved to be bought into the decision.

For something like developer tooling (which is a potentially contentious issue) I'd probably do 2 followed by either 3 or 4. i.e. there would definitely be some individuals I wouldn't talk to personally on the issue, but on the other hand most of the key people would get a chance to contribute to the decision making.

To me the **real red flag** would be around if you feel strongly that the wrong decision has been taken (wrong == it harms the company rather than just your favourite tool wan't chosen). How does management react when you raise this issue:

- Good management will listen to your argument, thank you sincerely for the feedback and reconsider their position *in the event that you have raised new insights*. They may still not agree with you and may stick to their decision, but they will appreciate that you have raised it with them and do you the courtesy of saying why they are sticking with their decision. They might even change the way they make such decisions in the future, and if you made good points may include you on their list of "smart people to ask".
- Bad management will get defensive, say that "the decision is made" and other such tactics to avoid facing the fact that they may have made a wrong decision. They may see you as a "troublemaker". The company suffers, as does your faith in management. This is a real red flag! Get out while you can!

Comment: There is a pretty big difference from an ide/editor and an scm or build system. and ide/editor is for personal use and usually tailored to the individual. The scm or build system is used globally by everyone. One of these things needs centralized management the other most definitely does not.

Comment: My answer was targeted at the management issues rather than the specific decision on IDEs per se. However there are also many good reasons to standardise on an IDE (e.g. skills, training, licensing costs, pair programming efficiency, integration with other tools, overall quality of IDE, support costs, deployment ease). In some contexts the right decision will be to standardise - you are incorrect if you think this can *always* be left to individual choice (even if this is the right decision in many situation)

Comment: Almost every reason to standardize and enforce an IDE for workflow that I can think of or that you have listed are bad reasons or red flags in and of themselves to me. You can pry my dotfiles and emacs setup from my cold dead fingers.

Comment: @Jeremy: I think your perspective is perfectly fine for a one-man-band or a small group of hackers. I sympathise strongly: I'm exactly the same for my own personal projects. But that approach simply doesn't scale to larger enterprise contexts. Having a preference for tools is fine, but I expect a good professional developer to be willing and able to learn and adopt whatever tools make the organisation most effective as a whole.

Comment: My perspective is shared by my employer Google who certainly qualifies as a larger enterprise context. I agree that a good professional developer should be willing to learn and adopt tools to make the organization most effective as a whole. I disagree that an ide or editor could ever fall into that category.

Comment: Cool, great company and you're lucky to work in a place that is able to operate as lots of "small groups of hackers" on relatively independent projects. Most big enterprises don't have that luxury, sadly. Think big bank that needs to hire and train 100 entry-level Java coders in India to work on maintaining call centre apps. Encouraging them all to be creative and choose their own IDE/build workflow is simply not going to work.

Comment: @mikera If any company thinks they need "… to hire and train 100 entry-level Java coders in India…" then that is a huge red flag right there. If the company thinks that the best approach to software is to throw tons of inexperienced people in a timezone that's shifted 8-11 hours (from the U.S., at least), it's probably not the sort of place that will be very satisfying to work. Or to provide much in the way of job security, either.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using maven or something similar, it shouldn't matter which IDE you are using. There might be cases where one is tied to a specific IDE like eclipse, if there are plugins you rely on.

I think you should be able to choose your own IDE, the IDE you are most productive in. However, as I already stated there are cases where it makes sense to use a standard IDE.

Comment: eg. if you want to do ADF, then JDeveloper is the natural choice, plugins for other ides may not have all the functionality.

Answer (score 12):

Every team I've ever been on has had a multiplicity of IDE and editors: Eclipse, Netbeans, IDEA, VIM, Emacs, Textmate, RubyMine -- it's never been an issue. Never.

To me this speaks to a misunderstanding at the high levels of the organization, as to what really matters. What matters is letting good coders do what they need to do and use the tools that make them most comfortable. IDE uniformity has very little to do with the real communication that takes place about the essential questions of object architecture, unit testing, algorithms, etc.

Having the same IDE as the next guy just means that we both know how to browse the code with the same shortcuts, and how our compilation/configuration is set up. None of which will matter when talking about real code issues.

Look, it's livable, depending on other factors at the company. You can always use your own preferred editor for day-to-day stuff. And maybe your group is doing other great things that creates great culture. But mandated IDEs is a huge misstep IMO. For me, if *I* were interviewing with a company and they informed me which IDE I was *allowed* to use, I would thank them politely for their time.

Answer (score 11):

I'd have the "corporate mandated" IDE installed, but would still do most of my work in whatever IDE I wanted--it's not like anybody can tell what IDE was used to edit a source file.

On the IDE vs. editor front... for almost all languages, I *strongly* prefer an IDE (IntelliJ) because there's just so much more it can do for you than an editor can. There are some things I revert to ST2 or Emacs for, but for day-to-day coding, despite how much I like both ST2/Emacs, the IDE almost always wins.

Comment: I dispute your assertion that an IDE can do significantly more than an editor. There are clearly inferior editors , e.g. you wouldn't do serious development with nano or gedit, but I can code faster in vim than I, and I would guess most others, can in an IDE.  And though I hate to defend emacs, I'm sure an experienced emacs user is faster in emacs than an IDE as well.

Comment: @Kevin Dispute away--I'm a *long*-time Emacs user, and getting better with ST2, and there's simply no comparison. Better, more-context-sensitive completion, tighter debugging integration, there aren't *too* many things for which I'd give the nod to a text editor. Some languages fare better than others, for example, I wouldn't code Java in Emacs pretty much no matter what, for Ruby and Python I'm about half-and-half, but IntelliJ is winning me over. For actual *text* editing, whether it's code or not, I use an editor.

Comment: I know the question and most responses are geared towards the Java world, but over here in Microsoft's .NET world, the idea that an editor could be better than the mainstream IDE (Visual Studio) is absolutely retarded. I would not hire a .NET dev who insisted on using Notepad++ over Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8):

In [our Ruby shop](http://makandra.com/) there's a strong recommendation to use the IDE most of the team enjoys (RubyMine), because we know it does the job and we can teach each other shortcuts etc.

Developers are free to use a different IDE, but we require them to have solid skills in that editor should they choose so. If we see someone struggling to navigate their project or edit text in their custom FooEdit, RubyMine for them it is.

Answer (score 5):

If a programmer is an expert at a given IDE, then they should use it. If they aren't an expert at any IDE, there's probably one or two that are very common for your programming language, or within your team, and it probably makes sense for them to learn it.

Being forced to standardize on an IDE sounds like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

This is a massive red flag. Every company has a few such stupid ideas, but if other red flags keep coming, just leave.

Comment: Disagree. Many great companies make decisions fast, and if they make a mistake then listen to feedback and iterate. They don't waste time getting bogged down in endless consultations for every decision.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons for a company to force a particular editor or software in general on their developers should be examined. The paranoid (maybe not the word I am looking for) part of me thinks there might be some sort of productivity tracking added to the eclipse they are asking developers to install. A much less paranoid (again) thought would be that they have spent time adding product build tools to this IDE that would make things much easier if everyone pressed the same button to test and build their code branch.

Anyway what I am trying to say is its probably more than just mere bureaucracy, or a method of messing with the developers heads.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy for the motivation behind some decisions to get lost - especially with rapidly growing team. The motivation to move to Eclipse might just be the fact that most of the developers seem to be wasting a lot of time just configuring the IDE and that there is only limited expertise withing your company.

I would just take the order to move to Eclipse to mean that you should have Eclipse setup in case it is needed, but continue your work in your favorite editor. (You might have to move to Eclipse gradually if your company starts deploying cool tools within Eclipse.)

Red Flag: I would wait if there are a few more such irrational orders before being worried.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is a bad idea. It is inevitable that the team will become less productive since they have to learn to use new tools. And even then they won't be as effective as with the tools they already **grok**.

Since I've tried various tools myself I always had at some point that  feeling "gosh, this editor is annoying me with <insert some bug/difference from prefered tool>". So it'll be a moral drawback as well.

But of course there are also pros to have a whole team use the same tools. Sharing configs, skripts, plugins and all that sort of stuff. Which wouldn't be possible with a diversity of toolsets.

On the other hand… that last bit wouldn't be necessary if everyone used his or her preferred software. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A startup is generally trying to stay agile long enough to figure out a sustainable business model. Once it figures out the money part, management moves in to scale up the business. That's generally when all the early tech employees start leaving, as engineering processes gets tightened up.

As you know, you don't know what code will actually do until you run it. Turing proved that in the early days of computing. This means that there is no such thing as any meaningful measure of productivity when it comes to writing software. However, for management to do its job, productivity must be legible. Since you can't measure code (and people have tried -- lines of code, for example), they will measure what they can see. Programmers are more legible than the software they develop. The typical management team attempts to control programmers in order to make these things legible to them (instead of doing their real jobs: getting out of the way). And because they measure the wrong things, it doesn't work very well.

Having said that, you can still go a long way with a loosely-coupled team. Github's development team has around 50 people and they break every rule in the business management textbooks. They seem to be doing all right. Bugs get fixed (eventually). Features get added. Fires get put out.

What is a big red flag is if they are trying to scale things up without having figured out how to make money. At that point, you got to wonder how much of your unvested options and grants are really worth.

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to the question. Did you mean to post elsewhere?

Comment: @Daenyth I mean to post this here. The original headline "One IDE to rule them all?" had nothing to do with the explanatory paragraph. The OP seems to be asking if being forced to use an IDE indicates time to bail from the company.

Answer (score 0):

You can "use" Eclipse while still typing in SublimeText2.

This means having Eclipse installed and configured for your projects and getting up to speed with it so that you are equally comfortable using it if, say, pair programming. Nobody will (or at least should) care what editor you actually used to type in a piece of code you committed as long as maintaining your parallel setup doesn't take up an undue amount of time and you don't cut yourself off from the standard development environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Git and your branching is down, you shouldn't need to be using each other's editors anyway. You can just push a branch and have another dev pull it to get it working if he really can't figure your toolset out. Forcing everyone to use the same editor sounds like an order by some business head who wants to look smart but doesn't really understand the way you guys operate.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about this from a management point of view, the reason they may be doing this is for legal compliance.  The company is responsible to ensure that every tool used is being used legally and will also not encumber the product that is being developed.  (Some editors are free for personal use, but not free for any other purposes, etc.)  To audit every tool that every developer may want to use can be expensive. I've seen that on projects where time lines are tight, management will be cautious about which tools/libraries/etc are used to minimize changes later in the project that are directed by the legal folks.

On higher security projects there is also the concern of where the IDEs store temporary files, and what information is stored between sessions.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the reasons they have to recommend Eclipse. If developers are having trouble setting up their environments because everyone organizes things differently, there may be a reason to recommend a straightjacket. If, however, everybody was happy and productive using whatever they wanted, there is little reason to impose a change on something so deeply involved in the creative process.

Eclipse is a lot more than an editor - you may keep using your favorite editor for editing your code and rely on Eclipse for source control, debugging and whatever else the corporate mandated workflow wants it used for.

One final thing - enforcing process in this level may indicate the company intends to expand the development team and wants to have a certain bit of structure in place so new teammates can get productive faster. If you think Rails (or Django) as an "opinionated" framework, you'll realize having structure helps to understand  new applications easier.

Answer (score 0):

The red flag is not so much that a single IDE/editor is being forced upon every developer, but that this decision, and especially the decision on which IDE/editor was to be used was not made by all the developers, and perhaps none of them!?!

Certainly it would be best for the developers to reach a consensus, especially because they are obviously best qualified for the decision (at least on which editor/IDE). There may be good reason to conform and that decision should weigh-in the preference of management, but which editor/IDE should have been the decision of all the developers.

Getting 12 developers to cast some votes would be easy. Certainly there was time enough to do that! The conclusion would have been painful for some anyways and it might have even ended up being Eclipse in the end, but labeling the requirement as a "red flag" in that case would be much more debatable.